# Processing an Integer Buried in a String in XSL

Tags: xslt

I have a stored time value which is of the format `H:mm:ss`.  The hours may be any value from 0 up through several days.  This data is sent in an XML tag and processed by XSL to be displayed.  The display that I want is of the format:

`D days, HH:mm:ss (hours/minutes)`

Where the last tag shows hours if HH is greater than 0, minutes if it is 0.

Given the original HH, which may be more than 24, I know I need the floor of HH / 24 to get the days value.  Then the original HH % 24 gives me the leftover hours.

I have also handled the minutes and hours question using `xsl:when` and `xsl:if`.

It's getting days and hours from the hours value that has me stumped.

**EDIT**
So far, I'm looking at doing the following:

Variable declaration

```
<xsl:variable name="time"><xsl:value-of select="time" /><xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="days"><xsl:value-of select="floor(substring-before(time, ':') / 24)" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="hours"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(time, ':') mod 24" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="minutes"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(time, ':')" /></xsl:variable>
```

Use

```
<xsl:if test="$days > 0">
    <xsl:value-of select="$days" /> days
</xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="$hours" />:<xsl:value-of select="$minutes" />

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$hours > 0">
        hour<xsl:if test="$hours > 1">s</xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       minute<xsl:if test="$minute != '01:00'">s</xsl:if>
    </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

And for clarification, a sample time would be `<time>26:15:00</time>` for 1 day 2:15 hours.

Comment: What is the actual question? Do you have a sample piece of code that depicts what you are currently trying to do?

Comment: @dboarman-FissureStudios - I have updated with a stab at the code and hopefully clarified my question a bit more.  What I need to do is figure out how to get the days given the format in hours, minutes, and seconds and manipulate it into a nice string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the modifications I needed to make my original attempt work.  I needed to remember my dollar signs for variables.  I needed to use `div` instead of `/`.  Most importantly, I needed the expression `number` to cast the substring a number.  This is what I've come up with.  I welcome commentary that will improve my XSLT, though!

```
<xsl:variable name="time"><xsl:value-of select="time" /><xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="totalHours><xsl:value-of select="number(substring-before($time, ':'))" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="days"><xsl:value-of select="floor($totalHours div 24)" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="hours"><xsl:value-of select="$totalHours mod 24" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="minutes"><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(time, ':')" /></xsl:variable>
```